# Blade render from database

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

In my view I have this code:

```
{{L::getSomeContent('content')}}
```

This method returns content from the database. My question is, is it possible to return and render Blade straight from the database? For example, I have stored in the database:

```
<img src"{{asset('somepath')}}">
```

But when rendering this data straight from the database, it will just show like '%7%7'

I have tried `Blade::compileString`

Comment: Which laravel version?

Comment: Version: Laravel 4.2

Comment: `Blade::compileString()` should work. What did you get from that?

Comment: For the image example it will return this: <img src="&lt;?php echo e(asset('somepath')); ?&gt;"

Comment: I saw this some time ago in the source of a Laravel package for backend code for jQuery datatables. Search for the method 'blader'. https://github.com/bllim/laravel4-datatables-package/blob/master/src/Bllim/Datatables/Datatables.php

Answer (score 2):

I hate to suggest this, but `eval` would work in this case. Before you use this, you have to make sure that the content you pass to it isn't user input. And if it is you have to sanitize it (or trust the user, if the content can be changed in some kind of admin tool)

Instead of using this method you should maybe thinking of some other way to organize your content. For paths you could use a placeholder and just do a string replace before outputting.

*Anyhow, be warned: **`eval()` will execute any PHP code** that's passed.*

Here's a working example. Of course you put that in some kind of helper function to not clutter your view code, but I'll leave that to you.

```
<?php
    $blade = L::getSomeContent('content');
    $php = Blade::compileString($blade);
    // remove php brackets because eval() doesn't like them
    $php = str_replace(['<?php', '?>'], '', $php);
    echo eval($php);
?>
```

---

As I already mentioned for this particular case (a path to an asset) you could use a placeholder in your content. For example:

Stored in the database

```
<img src"%ASSET%some/path">
```

And then inside a helper function and before output, just replace it with the real path:

```
$content = L::getSomeContent('content');
$html = str_replace('%ASSET%', asset(''), $content);
```

Comment: Although this answer is completely correct, it should NEVER be used. Generally if you're using a framework and you end up putting `eval()` in your template, your approach needs revising.

Comment: @Joe I totally agree. Unfortunately I don't think there's another way (besides changing the existing content system)

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer in the comments @blablabla :

```
protected function blader($str, $data = array())
{
    $empty_filesystem_instance = new Filesystem;
    $blade = new BladeCompiler($empty_filesystem_instance, 'datatables');
    $parsed_string = $blade->compileString($str);
    ob_start() and extract($data, EXTR_SKIP);
    try {
        eval('?>' . $parsed_string);
    }
    catch (\Exception $e) {
        ob_end_clean();
        throw $e;
    }
    $str = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    return $str;
}
```

This part seems to be working fine:

```
Blade::compileString($yourstring);
eval('?>' . $yourstring);
```